# Will there be a Plane Shift for Eldraine

Tags: dnd-5e, mtg-plane-shift

[Plane shift](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Plane_Shift) are free D&D5 supplements that allow you to play your D&D Campaign in some of the universes of Magic The Gathering. Since Zendikar, there has always been a Plane Shift for the released sets (except core sets and Ravnica, that has got a bigger book).

The set has been out for less than a month, but I've been unable to find one for Throne of Eldraine. Will there be one?

Thanks

Comment: Hi! To be honnest, I wasn't sure if this was the right place to ask it. But I also knew that this is the place where I could find and answer. Could you tell me the proper place to ask it? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Unless someone is a time-traveler, I don't think it's possible to know whether there "will be" one at some unspecified point in the future, no matter where you ask... So I'm not sure we can really direct you to a more appropriate place. We do have [this curated list of forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go) on meta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Probably not, since they're tied to the *Art of ...* books.

James Wyatt, who does the Plane Shift booklets, says in the [general FAQ](http://roleplaying.aquela.com/plane-shift):

> Q: When will you do Plane Shift: [My Favorite Plane]?
>
> A: For the foreseeable future, Plane Shift is inextricably linked with art books. And art books are inextricably linked with set releases.

and [on his Twitter](https://twitter.com/aquelajames/status/1176238964631453696):

> I can finally confirm that we do not have an #mtgEldraine art book in the works.

Comment: Well, I'm disapointed with that fact, thanks for your answer